# Slice all except first element, unless single element

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'd like to slice a numpy array to get all but the first item, unless there's only one element, in which case, I only want to select that element (i.e. don't slice).

Is there a way to do this without using an if-statement?

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1])
print(x[1:]) # works
print(y[1 or None:]) # doesn't work
```

I tried the above, but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you want if there *is* only one element?

Comment: Sorry, I just want that element. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to write that without a conditional is to use negative indexing with `-len(arr) + 1`:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> y = np.array([1])

>>> x[-len(x)+1:]
array([2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> y[-len(y)+1:]
array([1])
```

If the array has *N* elements where *N > 1*, slice becomes `-N+1:`. Since *-N+1 < 0*, it is effectively `(N + (-N + 1)): === 1:`, i.e, first one onwards.

Elsewhen *N == 1*, slice is `0:`, i.e., take the first element onwards which is the only element.

Because of how slicing works, an empty array (i.e., *N = 0* case) will result in an empty array too.

Comment: @vsocrates OK, maybe this works, but for the sake of anyone reading your code in the future, including yourself in a year or two, please don't do this! Think about legibility. An if statement here would make the code's intent clear. The more concise code just makes things cryptic.

Comment: I would frankly use the more verbose `y[0] if len(y) == 1 else y[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

You can just write an if / else:

```
x[1 if len(x) > 1 else 0:]
array([2, 3, 4, 5])

y[1 if len(y) > 1 else 0:]
array([1])
```

Or:

```
y[int(len(y) > 1):]
array([1])

x[int(len(x) > 1):]
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Looks like I'll have to write some sort of conditional. Just wondering if there was a clever numpy way to do it. I do like the 3rd option, even though it's not quite as clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just move None out of the brackets

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1]
print(x[1:]) 
print(y[1:] or None)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but sorry, my mistake. I want to keep the single element array then. Updated the question.

Comment: you could just write `or y` instead. However, if you do this with numpy arrays, Numpy will emit a warning.

Comment: then just use y instead of None:
```x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1]
print(x[1:])
print(y[1:] or y)
print(x[1:] or x)```

Answer (score 0):

Check the array size is greater than 1 if the case you can delete the first element from array and it will give new array without it.

print(np.delete(x, 0))

Now you can get a new array which  will contain only remaining items other than first.

Comment: These are numpy arrays, I can't pop them.

Comment: Can't you just delete first element print(np.delete(x, 0)) this will give a new array without first element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary expression to make the logic clear but still be able to use it as a function argument or inside other expressions.

The ternary expression `x if len(x) == 1 else x[1:]` works and is very clear. And you can use it as a parameter in a function call, or in a larger expression.

E.g.:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> y = np.array([1])
>>> print(x if len(x) == 1 else x[1:])
[2 3 4 5]
>>> print(y if len(y) == 1 else y[1:])
[1]
```

**Musings on other solutions**

I'm not sure if you're looking for the most concise code possible to do this, or just for the ability to have the logic inside a single expression.

I don't recommend fancy slicing solutions with negative indexing, for the sake of legibility of your code. Think about future readers of your code, even yourself in a year or two.

**Using this is a larger expression**

In the comments, you mention you need a solution that can be incorporated into something like a comprehension. The ternary expression can be used as is within a comprehension. For example, this code works:

```py
l = [np.array(range(i)) for i in range(5)]
l2 = [
    x if len(x) == 1 else x[1:]
    for x in l
]
```

I've added spacing to make the code easier to read, but it would also work as a one liner:

```py
l2 = [x if len(x) == 1 else x[1:] for x in l]
```

**EDIT note**

Earlier, I thought you wanted the first element extracted from the list in the single-element case, i.e., `x[0]`, but I believe you actually want that single-element list unsliced, i.e., `x`, so I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The issue is the larger expression I'm using is a list comprehension. I don't think this solution works in that case. However, I do agree that readability is important, so I might use @Psidom's solution instead.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you can use a ternary expression in a comprehension, I've seen it in my code base before, in stuff written by colleagues. But of course, the best solution is certainly the one that works in your actual code.